# Sprite icon in TMP with text inside

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

Using TMP sprite in string as in this example :

```
"Some text before {amount}<sprite name="my_sprite"> and some text after"
```

where the expected result would be the following:

[image]

In this context, I should be able to make "2" any given number on top of the icon below but I can't figure out how to have those overlapping.